# Динамические объекты в Vaadin

Tags: java, vaadin

```
import com.vaadin.data.util.IndexedContainer;
import com.vaadin.ui.Alignment;
import com.vaadin.ui.Button;
import com.vaadin.ui.GridLayout;
import com.vaadin.ui.Label;
import com.vaadin.ui.Table;
import com.vaadin.ui.TextField;
import com.vaadin.ui.VerticalLayout;
import com.vaadin.ui.Window;
import com.vaadin.ui.themes.Reindeer;

/**
 *
 * @author Neiron
 */
public class Phonebook extends MCS {

Table table = new Table("Телефонный справочник");
final IndexedContainer c = TableUtil.getContainer();

/**
 * Создаёт Layout с таблицей телефонов
 */
public VerticalLayout getPhonebook () {
    //table init

    //size
    table.setWidth("100%");
    table.setHeight("100%");

    // connect data source

    table.setContainerDataSource(c);

    // turn on column reordering and collapsing
    table.setColumnReorderingAllowed(true);
    table.setColumnCollapsingAllowed(true);

    // set column headers
    table.setColumnHeaders(new String[]{"ФИО", "Отдел/Должность", "Внутрненний тел.", "Городской тел.", "Сотовый тел.", "Email"});

    //table init end

    final VerticalLayout contentIndex = new VerticalLayout();
    contentIndex.setMargin(true);

    Button button_filter = new Button("Фильтр");
    button_filter.setStyleName(Reindeer.BUTTON_SMALL);
    button_filter.addListener(new Button.ClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void buttonClick (Button.ClickEvent event) {
            main.addWindow(filterWindow());
        }
    });
    //Filter end

    contentIndex.addComponent(button_filter);
    contentIndex.addComponent(table);
    return contentIndex;
}

public Window filterWindow () {
    // Filter start
    final Window window_filter = new Window("Фильтр");
    window_filter.setHeight("320");
    window_filter.setWidth("320");
    window_filter.center();
    window_filter.setStyleName(Reindeer.WINDOW_LIGHT);
    window_filter.setResizable(false);

    final GridLayout filter_grid = new GridLayout(2, 7);
    filter_grid.setSpacing(true);
    filter_grid.setSizeFull();
    // FIO
    Label fio = new Label("ФИО");
    filter_grid.addComponent(fio, 0, 0);
    final TextField fio_textfield = new TextField();
    filter_grid.addComponent(fio_textfield, 1, 0);
    // Otdel
    Label otdel = new Label("Отдел, Должность");
    filter_grid.addComponent(otdel, 0, 1);
    final TextField otdel_textfield = new TextField();
    filter_grid.addComponent(otdel_textfield, 1, 1);
    // Tel V
    Label tel_v = new Label("Внут. тел.");
    filter_grid.addComponent(tel_v, 0, 2);
    final TextField tel_v_textfield = new TextField();
    filter_grid.addComponent(tel_v_textfield, 1, 2);
    // Tel G
    Label tel_g = new Label("Город. тел.");
    filter_grid.addComponent(tel_g, 0, 3);
    final TextField tel_g_textfield = new TextField();
    filter_grid.addComponent(tel_g_textfield, 1, 3);
    // Tel S
    Label tel_s = new Label("Сотов. тел.");
    filter_grid.addComponent(tel_s, 0, 4);
    final TextField tel_s_textfield = new TextField();
    filter_grid.addComponent(tel_s_textfield, 1, 4);
    // Email
    Label email = new Label("Email");
    filter_grid.addComponent(email, 0, 5);
    final TextField email_textfield = new TextField();
    filter_grid.addComponent(email_textfield, 1, 5);

    final Button filter_button = new Button("Отфильтровать");
    filter_button.addListener(new Button.ClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void buttonClick (Button.ClickEvent event) {
            c.removeAllContainerFilters();
            c.addContainerFilter(TableUtil.PROPERTY_NAME, fio_textfield.toString(), true, true);
            c.addContainerFilter(TableUtil.PROPERTY_OTDEL, otdel_textfield.toString(), true, true);
            c.addContainerFilter(TableUtil.PROPERTY_TEL_V, tel_v_textfield.toString(), true, true);
            c.addContainerFilter(TableUtil.PROPERTY_TEL_G, tel_g_textfield.toString(), true, true);
            c.addContainerFilter(TableUtil.PROPERTY_TEL_S, tel_s_textfield.toString(), true, true);
            c.addContainerFilter(TableUtil.PROPERTY_EMAIL, email_textfield.toString(), true, true);
        }
    });
    filter_grid.addComponent(filter_button, 0, 6);

    final Button filter_reset_button = new Button("Сбросить");
    filter_reset_button.addListener(new Button.ClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void buttonClick (Button.ClickEvent event) {
            c.removeAllContainerFilters();
        }
    });
    filter_grid.addComponent(filter_reset_button, 1, 6);
    filter_grid.setComponentAlignment(filter_reset_button, Alignment.BOTTOM_LEFT);
    filter_grid.setComponentAlignment(filter_button, Alignment.BOTTOM_RIGHT);

    window_filter.addComponent(filter_grid);
    return window_filter;
}
}
```

Всю голову уже сломал. Суть следующая: есть динамический класс, в нём по методу `getPhonebook ()` строится `VerticalLayout` с таблицей номеров телефонов. Также на этом слое есть кнопка и листенер для неё, на неё повешен метод  `filterWindow()`, который рисует окно с полями для фильтрации списка номеров по параметрам.

Проблема в том, что окно фильтра списка не появляется и не выдаётся никаких ошибок. Я сделал вывод, что оно появилось в другой динамической копии. Как вылечить это?

Comment: @hitman249 вы как то определитесь с вопросами: а то бардак - 2 вопроса в одном посте - непорядок. Закрываю для профилактики.

Comment: @hitman249 Нужно создавать [отдельную тему](http://hashcode.ru/questions/140725/) для отдельного вопроса.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это к проблеме имеет косвенное отношение, но...

```
public TextField createTextField(GridLayout grid, int rowindex, String title) {
    // create label
    Label label = new Label(title);
    grid.addComponent(label, 0, rowindex);

    // create text field
    TextField textField = new TextField();
    grid.addComponent(textField, 1, rowindex);

    return textField;
}

//
int row = 0;
TextField fio   = createTextField(filter_grid, row++, "FIO");
TextField otdel = createTextField(filter_grid, row++, "Отдел, Должность");
...
```

Comment: Ну, что вы, я тут с 2-мя динамическими методами справиться не могу, а вы такое предлагаете, но спасибо. )