# Как правильно выполнить метод 2 в методе 1?

Tags: java, vaadin

Такой вопрос, как правильно выполнить метод 2 в методе 1? При такой картине (все методы динамические)

```
Какой-то другой класс {  
    В нём какой-то метод() {  
        К к = new K();  
        к.метод1();
    }  
}  

class К {  
    глобальная переменная = п;  
    метод1 () {дёргает п; дергает метод2}  
    метод2 () {дёргает(изменяет) п;}  
}
```

> Сделано вопросом из комментария в теме: [динамические объекты в Vaadin](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/140587/).

Comment: Впервые слышу о "динамических методах". Что вы подразумеваете под этим термином?

Comment: скорее всего тем что они не статические))). а вообще да, такого термина в java нет

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ну есть как минимум два варианта (на самом деле одно и то же):

1.Передаем ссылку на объект в метод1 и вызываем метод2 используя эту ссылку:

```
class A{
     void a(){
     K k=new K();
     k.meth1(k);
     }
}
class K{
    void meth1(K k){k.meth2();}
    void meth2(){}
}
```

2.Используем ключевое слово `this` в значении ссылки на вызвавший метод объект:

```
class A{
    void a(){
    K k=new K();
    k.meth1();
    }
}
class K{
    void meth1(){this.meth2();}
    void meth2(){}
}
```